# .Net Core send/receive JSON over TCP

Tags: json, tcp, .net-core

I want to send and receive JSON over TCP. 
QUESTION: I have to send and receive JSON in my TCP client-server. How can I achieve it?

I use TcpListener and TcpClient to connect and I have this code:

```
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream, new UTF8Encoding(), false);
    var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
    var data = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader).ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    writer.WriteValue('1');
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Can I do it better? The client has to receive JSON(I use Newtonsoft.Json) and I don't know if it is even good code. Maybe you write me some good practices? Or maybe some tips.

**EDIT.**
Now I wrote something like this:

```
public static T DeserializeFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work because Java client send me array like:  [{"name" : "logo", "session" : "i3fnj34njn780"}] So how can I fix this problem? I want call it this way: `Method ar = DeserializeFromStream<Method>(client.GetStream());` Trim and Replace doesn't work for me here.

Comment: If you don't know anything about sockets, why are you using sockets? Just use a higher-level protocol, such as HTTP. It's well-defined, properly implemented and thoroughly tested, as opposed to any code you and I can come up with. Anyway read [ask]. We aren't going to throw general hints your way, you'll have to have an actual question.

Comment: @CodeCaster but I don't use HTTP protocol

Comment: No, I can clearly see that, hence my remark. But you need an application protocol on top of TCP anyway if you want to have any meaningful exchange of data.

Comment: @CodeCaster in Java you can type outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); so why I cannot do the same in C#?

Comment: You can, it's just not what you want to do. What are you trying to do and why do you think you need to use sockets for that? Handling sockets properly is not trivial, that's why I suggest to use HTTP, for which plenty of libraries exist.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok I need to rethink my concept. I have application on phone(Android) which need to receive JSON, and server(.net core) which need to send JSON

Comment: Yes, so that sounds like an ideal candidate for HTTP. Build a Web API and let the Android app download the JSON data over HTTP and you're done. No need to use sockets yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have no access to code for Android. So I can still use HTTP?

Comment: That depends on how the app reads the JSON, which should have been in your question to begin with. If it just connects to a socket, reads whatever it gets sent and then closes the connection again, then that's the "protocol" you'll have to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
```

This is incorrect. Per [RFC4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> 3. Encoding
>
>    JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>      UTF-8.

You are **not** sending JSON.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
```

This is unnecessarily writing a SB. Write directly into the network stream:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(tw)) {
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

Also, use `using`.

Plus, everything @CodeCaster says. This should be a proper Web API, not some rogue TCP server. Not only the obvious issue of having more than one request type (ie. routing), but you have to consider proxies (none will allow some arbitrary port), server authentication (you must tunnel through HTTPS and validate the server cert in the Android APP), make allowance for web caching, HTTP headers etc etc. And you need proper error states and error codes for your 'protocol', which HTTP provides out-of-the-box. And a good job would be to model a proper [REST API](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15299675-the-rest-api-design-handbook), and likely a good data model *on top of* JSON, like [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/).

Comment: The approach is still broken, because you can't detect whether `11` on the wire actually is one JSON message which contains the number 11 or two JSON messages which contain the number 1. There needs to be some framing protocol around messages, e.g. by length prefixing. Or by some magic delimiters. It works if a connection should only send one message front and back during it's whole lifetime, but I guess that's not what is expected.